# Run WSO2 IS with passive STS behind HTTPD Server

Tags: apache, tomcat, wso2, single-sign-on

My **Apache Webserver** (version 2.4) is behind a firewall and accessible from the internet. The Webserver is proxying the requests to the **WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0** which is running in the default **Apache Tomcat** (Port 9443). The WSO2 IS is used as Identity Provider and my Service Providers are applications using **passive STS** for authentication. Now I want the WSO2 IS to be available unter `/sso` and not root level `/`, because there are different other applications also mapped by this Apache Webserver.

Apache site configuration (snippet). The Apache is Listening to *Port 443* (SSL enabled)

```
<Location /sso >
    ProxyPass https://localhost:9443/sso
    ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:9443/sso
</Location>
```

Changes in `${CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/carbon.xml`

```
<WebContextRoot>/sso</WebContextRoot>
```

Changes in `${CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="9443"
            proxyPort="443"
            proxyName="my.ssosystem.com"
            bindOnInit="false"
            sslProtocol="TLS"
            maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
            acceptorThreadCount="2"
            maxThreads="250"
            minSpareThreads="50"
            disableUploadTimeout="false"
            enableLookups="false"
            connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
            maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
            acceptCount="200"
            server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
            clientAuth="false"
            compression="on"
            scheme="https"
            secure="true"
            SSLEnabled="true"
            compressionMinSize="2048"
            noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
            compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Now I have several problems

- Requesting `/sso/passivests` redirects me to the carbon admin login (`/sso/carbon/admin/login.jsp`) with a **302** instead to the `/sso/commonauth`
- After logging into the WSO IS as admin it works like expected but then I am redirected with a **302** to the `/authenticationendpoint` instead of `/sso/authenticationendpoint` . So I changed in `${CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/security/application-authentication.xml` the AuthenticationEndpointURL to `/sso/authenticationendpoint/login.do`. But then I receive the http error **405** (GET Method not allowed)

I thought this might be a common use case (Identity Server proxied by an Apache Webserver) but didn't find much information. Has anybody solved a similar issue or any idea?

Comment: I've got the same / similar problem.. did you manage to resolve this two issue? Seems the symptoms are the same even with newer version (WSO2 IS 5.0.0.SP1)